# unable to get table item in deleted section

Tags: reactjs

i have created a component in which i delete the table item its deleted i also want to add a button to add in the deleted item in the table done successfully but problem is that when I remove table item it item should be shown in the  deleted component here is my code

```
class Movies extends Component {
  state = {
    movies,
    deleted:[]
  };
  handleDelete = (_id) => {
    const movie = this.state.movies.find(movie => movie._id === _id);
    this.setState({ deleted: [...this.state.deleted, movie] });
    this.setState({movies:this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie._id !== _id)})
  };
  handleReinstate = (_id) => {
    const movie = this.state.deleted.find((movie) => movie._id === _id);
    this.setState({ movies:[ ...this.state.movies,movie] });
    this.setState({deleted:this.state.deleted.filter((movie) => movie._id !== _id)})
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.movies.map((movie) => {
              return(
            <tr key={movie._id}>
              <td>{movie.title}</td>
              <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
              <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
              <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
              <td
                onClick={() => this.handleDelete(movie._id)}
                className="btn  btn-danger btn-outline-warning btn-sm active "
              >
                Remove
              </td>
                
            </tr>
          )})}
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <h1>deleted</h1>
          {this.state.deleted.map(movie => (
            <tr key={movie._id}>
                
              
                <td
                    onClick={() => this.handleReinstate(movie._id)}
                    className="btn  btn-danger btn-outline-primary btn-sm active "
                >
                ADD
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>

    );
  }
}
```

I want to show like this but failed
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? What have you tried to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

adding this will solve problem

```
 {this.state.deleted.map(movie => (
            <tr key={movie._id}>
                <td>{movie.title}</td>
              <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
              <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
              <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
                <td
                    onClick={() => this.handleReinstate(movie._id)}
                    className="btn  btn-danger btn-outline-primary btn-sm active "
                >
                ADD
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
```